# Start a process in custom desktop with ShellExecute call

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, createprocess, shellexecute

I am working on a feasibility task, where I need to start an application in a custom desktop (programmatically created desktop, using `CreateDesktop()`).

Scenario:

ConsoleTestApplication: Use `ShellExecute()` to start an MFC application, LaunchingApp

LaunchingApp: Creates a new custom desktop and start a WPF application using `ShellExecute()`. The WPF application should open in the custom desktop.

The above scenario works while using `CreateProcess()`. When I tried with `ShellExecute()`, the custom desktop just glitched away, and didn't work.

Does `ShellExecute()` work along with custom desktop creation?

Is there any possible way to solve the above scenario using `ShellExecute()`? Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need to use `ShellExecute` when you can call `CreateProcess`? Why do you assume that `ShellExecute` is a vital part of the solution?

Comment: `ShellExecute` should never be used. `ShellExecuteEx` is for executing shell verbs. `CreateProcess` is for creating processes.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `ShellExecute()` nor `ShellExecuteEx()` support launching processes on alternative desktops, only on the desktop of the calling thread.

So, you would have to either use `SetThreadDesktop()` before `ShellExecute/Ex()`, or else just use `CreateProcess()` instead, which supports alternative desktops, as you noted.

`ShellExecute/Ex()` will simply delegate to `CreateProcess()` when launching an EXE file, so you really should just use `CreateProcess()` directly.  Use `ShellExecute/Ex()` only when launching data files (or when you need to force an EXE to launch with UAC elevation).